# Workflow : Best way to carry my projects over to multiple computers?

Tags: workspace, projects

I wonder if this question really fall in the topic of this site and feel free to tell me if it doesn't. But anyway, here's the situation : I'm currently in college and when I'm at school, I program on my lap top, and when I'm at home, I'd like to programm on my desktop. I was wondering, what is the best way to carry my projects over from one PC to another? I currently use Visual Studio 2015.

I tought of one solution, set my VS Workspace in my Google Drive so everytime I save a project, it's carried over.

But do you guys have a better solution? Thanks for your responses! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also don't know whether this question belongs to SO. Anyway, I will try to answer your question.

In situation where you program in groups, a [source code management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) (version control) is absolutely necessary to synchronize code and avoid conflicts. A very popular one is [Git](https://git-scm.com/) which is used in many various projects in different programming languages. For other version control systems, look at the bottom of the wiki article.

It would be too much to explain Git (or version control in general) in this answer, but the general work flow is always the same: There is a server somewhere, an when you start coding you 'check out' your project, which means you copy the most recent updates to your local machine. When you are done, you commit the changes to the server. If you want to work on another computer, you just check your project out again. When finished, commit again.